# online vector file RGB to CMYK: light and blending issues

Tags: color, vector, cmyk, rgb, blend-modes

Most of the time due to design requirement, we have to download some free loyalty vector file online.

But due to print requirement we have to convert the color mode from RGB to CMYK. This was much of the issue.

But the problem occurs when the the vector consist of highlight: when the mode changes to CMYK, the part with overlay doesn't blend in the black anymore.

Is there any solution to the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I deal with this problem weekly almost. 
Usually I'll drop the file into Illustrator, export the file to an RGB JPG, convert the vector to CMYK, import the JPG I just exported. Now I have a reference for how it should look (you won't get it exactly the same).

Once converting to CMYK whatever objects had blend modes on (multiply and screen, I think) will change completely. I just select them all, make them either plain white or full K with color added to make it blend properly. Then I set the blend mode for them all to multiply or overlay (whichever gives me the desired effect, I can never remember which does what I need until I pick them)

Hope I've helped.

Comment: But most of the time the file contain too many element. Adjusting them one by one ....that kinda pain in the ass ....

Comment: I'm not at my work PC, but I think in the 'Select' window there's a way to select objects that all have the same appearance/outline/fill color. Try using that.

Or you could use the edit menu and recolor the artwork entirely. That's a little more difficult, but it would be way faster.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best option is to keep working in RGB as long as you can. Convert the image to an RGB Bitmap and after that convert it to CMYK.